# Creating a new column by giving multiple conditions priority

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 20, 55],
        'b': [3, 40, 33],
        'c': [4, 50, 10]
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `d`.

```
    a   b   c    d
0  10   3   4  1.0
1  20  40  50  0.0
2  55  33  10  1.0
```

This is actually a weird and basic issue that I have. These are the conditions for creating column `d`:

```
df.loc[df.a > df.b, 'd'] = 1
df.loc[df.a > df.c, 'd'] = 2
df['d'] = df.d.fillna(0)
```

If I do it in order, `d` would be overwritten. I want it in this way: If for example `df.a > df.b`, `d` is 1. And it is done. Don't go for other conditions.
This was actually my try to create `d` but it obviously fails,

Comment: `df['d'] = np.select([df['a']>df['c'], df['a']>df['b']], [2,1], 0)`

Comment: @mozway Is it duplicate question?!!! maybe post it as answer and I accept. You are my hero :)

Comment: @mozway your answer does NOT give me the result

Comment: `df['d'] = np.select([df['a']>df['b'], df['a']>df['c']], [1, 2], 0)` depending on the priorities of conditions

Comment: Then the logic is unclear what has higher precedence? A>B or A>C?

Comment: @mozway I deleted that comment :) Thanks man. One day I will settle up with you.

Comment: If this worked you might want to correct your output to be either 1/0/1 or 2/0/2.

Comment: Note that your original code was fine, you just needed to invert the two `loc` lines ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah I thought about that. I was like what the hell :) Thanks again